# Fabric Twitter Login Android throwing errors

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

We have integrated twitter fabric twitter plugin into my eclipse android application. After all the step by step process was done, i am getting the error like

```
 11-12 19:01:54.263: E/NativeCrypto(22663): ssl=0x530f7cc0 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5248cab8 arg=0x0
 11-12 19:01:54.263: E/NativeCrypto(22663): ssl=0x530f7cc0 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
 11-12 19:01:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22663): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 11-12 19:01:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22663): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class       {om.example.testtwit/com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthAcctivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
 11-12 19:01:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22663):   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1624)
 11-12 19:01:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22663):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1423)
 11-12 19:01:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(22663):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3388)
```

Edited:

Hey thanks for your reply here is my login call back code automatically generated by fabric plugin :

```
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
       loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
         @Override
         public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
             // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
         }

         @Override
         public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
         }
        });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

and my build.gradle file :

```
         buildscript {
          repositories {
         jcenter()
         maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
          }
         dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
         // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
         // quickly to Android tooling updates
          classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
          }
          }

         apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
          apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

          repositories {
           jcenter()
           maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo' }
           }

           android {
           compileSdkVersion 19
           buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

           defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 19
             }
             }

           dependencies {
           // Crashlytics Kit
           compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.0.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
             }

           // Twitter Kit
           compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
             }

           // MoPub Kit
           compile('com.mopub.sdk.android:mopub:3.2.2@aar') {
           transitive = true
            }
             }
```

Comment: Can you show how you are instantiating the Login button and your dependencies on build file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the OAuthActivity in your project's manifest file.
I had the same issues, worked after putting the following lines in Androidmanifest.xml.

```
        <activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your code,, it worked for me. Even without this line , if the twitter app is being installed in the device,then it worked, but app crashes if twitter app is not there.After adding your line it worked in both the ways. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: @loadtest can you help me please how did you add twitter fabric kit to Eclipse? I have added to android studio and it is working well. Then, I added to Eclipse, and it is added successfully, but the classes and imports of twitter fabric are not resolved by the eclipse. For every class, the eclipse shows an error "cannot be resolved to a type". I have search around the web but didn't find any solution...

Comment: Hello @MuhammadSohail Have you been able to fix your issue? I'm having exactly the same issue.

Comment: @MarcVanDaele No, I'm still having the problem... :-(

Comment: Muhammad Sohail: what problem you are having?

Comment: @MuhammadSohail I fixed my issue in Eclipse with the help of support@fabric.io. My workspace contained a problematic (closed) project and fabric choked on it.  After removing the project, it started working as expected. The offending project could be found in the crashlytics.log. This file is located On Linux / Windows in 
~/.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse/logs/workspace-<YourSha1>/logs/crashlytics.log
On Mac in
~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics/com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse.core/workspace-<YourSha1>/logs/crashlytics.log

Comment: Hello guys : i am also getting error during login. i am using login in fragment. Please help me. Thanks in advance.