# Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity}

Tags: java, android

in a separate class not being activity there is a method for authorization on Twitter

```
public void login(){
      twitterAuthClient.authorize(new Activity() {
                @Override
                public void startActivityForResult(@RequiresPermission Intent intent, int requestCode) {
                    fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
                                    }


                @Override
                public PackageManager getPackageManager() {
                    return fragment.getContext().getPackageManager();
                }
            }, twitterAuthCallback);
      }
```

So here when this method works
`<activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />`, an error occurs

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity}; Have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Even after adding an actives file to the manifest, the error does not disappear.
I ask your help.

Comment: do you have twitter installed on the device? And please post your code where you call that activity in full. And full manifest

Comment: I think this link will help you..http://stackoverflow.com/a/26986844/7806873

Comment: The Twitter application is not installed. According to the terms of reference, it is assumed that authorization should be enforced, including without an application.I tried to solve the problem as advised on that link

Answer (score 0):

You Have to declare the OAuthActivity in your project's manifest file. Please putting the following lines in Androidmanifest.xml should work.

`<activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />`

Comment: In the manifest I added <activity android: name = "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />But the error is still present